# Additional Basemap Menu in ArcGIS Viewer for Flex?

Tags: arcgis-server, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am using ArcGIS Viewer for Flex 3.5 to create an application. As it covers more than one areas of interest, I need to provide an option to the user to only select base maps from his own desired domain. In order to do that,  I need more than one Basemap dropdown menus in the application whereas, the default map switcher widget only provides options for one menu.

I have not been able to find any worthwhile support or guidance for the same. The only relevant source of information which I could find is a thread related to similar task in sample flex viewer in old ESRI forums at this link: 
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2421&t=282643.

However, the flex code when compared the 3.5 version is no more relevant and I cannot figure out how to make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Application Builder. It allows you to choose multiple custom or ArcGIS Online basemaps for use in the application. Here are the [instructions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#/Maps_tab/01m300000041000000/) on how to do that. After you have build your application, you basically deploy a Flex Viewer application at your web server. If you still prefer to use the source code of Flex Viewer and do all the development on your own, then look for the [tag reference here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#/Map_content/01m30000005p000000/) which will help you to set additional basemaps in your configuration file.

Open config.xml and edit the basemaps tag:

```
<basemaps>
    <layer label="CustomBaseMap"
           type="tiled"
           visible="true"
           url="http://server/ArcGIS/rest/services/BaseMaps/BaseMap/MapServer"/>
</basemaps>
```